# What is the pros/cons of inheritence vs new Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I noticed from [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/63239/70065) that there's two ways of separating Contract code with state variables: **Inheritance** (class Contract **is** XY {}) or **Reference** (otherClass = new OtherClass())

I'm wondering what are the pros/cons of using one over the other.

In my mind, I expect initialising a `new Contract()` to be more expensive since it sounds like it's deploying; yet in that answer, he explains that all the contracts compile down to one in the end, so perhaps it is not more/less expensive.

So why would you choose one over the other?

Comment: you split contracts in multiple instances when they execute different functionality. And therefore can be reused by other contracts efficiently

Comment: @Nulik thanks, I understand that. My question is what are the pros and cons of each. i.e. why should I use inheritence vs new Contract()

Comment: this is more like OOP question, I suggest Java forums, or C++

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware that the second design I was referring to was composition pattern, have looked into that now.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the design of the project. You will see the difference when you work on a project or you go through a project step by step.

I remember there is a limitation if you wanna use inheritance contracts "Linearization of inheritance graph impossible"
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/contracts.html#multiple-inheritance-and-linearization

The size: it could be exceeded the maximum size for a contract because of duplications, for example.

Check the the access classifiers when use new contract() see the example
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters